# удаление лишнего перед выводом в webview

Tags: java, android, webview

Подскажите, есть такая задача: есть url страницы, содержащей много лишних элементов, как лучше их удалить перед выводом в webview или во время вывода ( просмотр постов в приложении)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу два варианта:

- на уровне Android модифицировать, достаточно легко подменить статические ресурсы, гораздо сложнее читать на лету. Например вот тут о сложностях: https://artemzin.com/blog/android-webview-io/
- модифицируйте DOM в JavaScript, большинство SPA работают. Заинжектить код в Webview можно например так https://stackoverflow.com/a/32163655/5892568 - однако возможны сложности связанные с Cross Site Origin.

В идеале лучше вам сделать промежуточный веб-сервис которы будет парсить веб, отдавать его в структурированном виде. В случае изменения разметки менять приложения будет очень проблематично, а так меняете сервис.